# Name of this C++ pattern and the reasoning behind it?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

In my company's C++ codebase I see a lot of classes defined like this:

```
// FooApi.h
class FooApi {
public:
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
    virtual void someOtherFunction() = 0;
    // etc.
};

// Foo.h
class Foo : public FooApi {
public:
    virtual void someFunction();
    virtual void someOtherFunction();
};
```

`Foo` is this only class that inherits from `FooApi` and functions that take or return pointers to `Foo` objects use `FooApi *` instead. It seems to mainly be used for singleton classes.

Is this a common, named way to write C++ code? And what is the point in it? I don't see how having a separate, pure abstract class that just defines the class's interface is useful.

**Edit[0]**: Sorry, just to clarify, there is only one class deriving from `FooApi` and no intention to add others later.

**Edit[1]**: I understand the point of abstraction and inheritance in general but not *this particular usage* of inheritance.

Comment: It's not really a design pattern but rather a core OOP concept

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: How do you know there is no intention of deriving other classes later? Even if the author has no intention of deriving from `FooApi` himself, he is leaving open the option for others to derive from it. Or leaving the option open for himself, if he decides later that he does in fact want to do that.

Comment: Because it's used repeatedly throughout a large codebase and all the abstract classes only have one derived class and they are all named after the derived class. ie. there are classes called Foo, FooApi, Bar, BarApi, Quxx, QuxxApi etc. Other parts of the code use inheritance normally and don't follow this naming scheme.

Comment: The name of this technique is *interface*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason that I can see why they would do this is for *encapsulation* purposes. The point here is that most other code in the code-base *only* requires inclusion of the "FooApi.h" / "BarApi.h" / "QuxxApi.h" headers. Only the parts of the code that *create* Foo objects would actually need to include the "Foo.h" header (and link with the object-file containing the definition of the class' functions). And for singletons, the only place where you would normally create a Foo object is in the "Foo.cpp" file (e.g., as a local static variable within a static member function of the Foo class, or something similar).

This is similar to using forward-declarations to avoid including the header that contains the actual class declaration. But when using forward-declarations, you still need to eventually include the header in order to be able to call any of the member functions. But when using this "abstract + actual" class pattern, you don't even need to include the "Foo.h" header to be able to call the member functions of FooApi.

In other words, this pattern provides very strong encapsulation of the Foo class' implementation (and complete declaration). You get roughly the same benefits as from using the [Compiler Firewall idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm). [Here](http://akhodakivskiy.github.io/2012/12/11/private-implementation-forward-declaration.html) is another interesting read on those issues.

I don't know the name of that pattern. It is not very common compared to the other two patterns I just mentioned (compiler firewall and forward declarations). This is probably because this method has quite a bit more run-time overhead than the other two methods.

Comment: `FooApi` is what Java et al. would call an "interface". Your answer provides solid C++ reasoning why separating the interface and the implementation is useful even when there is only a single implementor of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is for if the code is later added on to. Lets say `NewFoo` also extends/implements `FooApi`. All the current infrastructure will work with both `Foo` and `NewFoo`.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that this has been done for the same reason that pImpl ("pointer to implementation idiom", sometimes called "private implementation idiom") is used - to keep private implementation details out of the header, which means common build systems like make that use file timestamps to trigger code recompilation will not rebuild client code when only implementation has changed.  Instead, the object containing the new implementation can be linked against existing client object(s), and indeed if the implementation is distributed in a shared object (aka dynamic link library / DLL) the client application can pick up a changed implementation library the next time it runs (or does a `dlopen()` or equivalent if it's linking at run-time).  As well as facilitating distribution of updated implementation, it can reduce rebuilding times allowing a faster edit/test/edit/... cycle.

The cost of this is that implementations have to be accessed through out-of-line virtual dispatch, so there's a performance hit.  This is typically insignificant, but if a trivial function like a get-int-member is called millions of times in a performance critical loop it may be of interest - each call can easily be an order of magnitude slower than inlined member access.

What's the "name" for it?  Well, if you say you're using an "interface" most people will get the general idea.  That term's a bit vague in C++, as some people use it whenever a base class has virtual methods, others expect that the base will be abstract, lack data members and/or private member functions and/or function definitions (other than the virtual destructor's).  Expectations around the term "interface" are sometimes - for better or worse - influenced by Java's language keyword, which restricts the interface class to being abstract, containing no static methods or function definitions, with all functions being public, and only `const` `final` data members.

None of the well-known Gang of Four Design Patterns correspond to the usage you cite, and while doubtless lots of people have published (web- or otherwise) corresponding "patterns", they're probably not widely enough used (with the same meaning!) to be less confusing than "interface".

Answer (score 0):

`FooApi` is a virtual base class, it provides the interface for concrete implementations (`Foo`).

The point is you can implement functionality in terms of `FooApi` and create multiple implementations that satisfy its interface and still work with your functionality. You see some advantage when you have multiple descendants - the functionality can work with multiple implementations. One might implement a different type of Foo or for a different platform.

Re-reading my answer, I don't think I should talk about OO ever again.

Comment: The `virtual` keyword is not necessary; the methods will be virtual regardless of whether or not the keyword is present.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart In C++, member functions are non-virtual by default.

Comment: I get an error if I try and declare pure functions without virtual.

Comment: @JoshTownzen ...unless they are overriding a virtual method.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman The keyword is required whem first declaring the pure virtual functions. I was referring to your second point: once a method has been declared virtual, all method declarations that override it will implicitly be virtual.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Ah.  The original post didn't have `virtual` functions in the base class.  Those were edited in after Rhythmic Fistman mentioned they were missing.

Comment: I was referring to the question in which the functions were pure.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. Yes, everything should be declared virtual.

Comment: "I've edited my answer..." - almost there - "FooApi is a virtual base class" - it's not... it's just a base class with virtual functions which is a *completely* different thing.  Separately, "The point is...create multiple implementations" - the question specifically says this isn't being done, and it's quite possible there's no intention or potential for this to be necessary, and the technique's being done to hide implementation details and/or as a (re)compilation firewall (so a new implementation can be "linked" without a client code recompilation).

Comment: Thanks, I should've made the multiple vs singleton mismatch explicit. Re: VBC I had no idea! Objective-C has turned my brain to mush

Comment: @RhythmicFistman: lots of people get VBC confused... unsurprising as having pure virtual functions leads naturally to thoughts of virtual base classes, but the correct term there is "abstract base class", and "virtual base classes" are for shared use of a common base object instance by many of a derived class's other bases.